# Convert object back to file

Tags: asp.net

I want to convert an object of System.Byte[] which is actually a file, retrieved from the database, back to file and store the file in a folder. How can we convert it using ASP.Net with C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right way:

```
byte[] b = YourByteArrayFromDb;
File.WriteAllBytes(MyFilePath, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
byte[] b = YourByteArrayFromDb;
string s = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
File.WriteAllText(MyFilePath, s);
```

Given that this is an ASP.Net application, you may run into permission issues writing to the file system.  Place your code in a try/catch block and provide a reasonable error message or log entry if you can't write the file.

If your original file was not encoded in ASCII, you will need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Or just use File.WriteAllBytes(MyFilePath, b)

Comment: WriteAllBytes literally writes the bytes to a file, without the ability to interpret encoding.  If that's what's needed here, that is a shorter solution.